# Does Bootcamp support 64 bit version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I have just purchased a Macbook Pro which will run OS X Lion. Which version of Windows can I run in Bootcamp? 64 or 32 bit? Both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version 4.0 of Bootcamp for Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4840), released July 20, 2011, drops support for all versions of Windows XP and Vista.

It supports 32-bit or 64-bit Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium, Professional, or Ultimate.

#### [Boot Camp 4.0 FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818) from Apple Support.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846

Answer (score 1):

You can run Windows 7 in either 32- or 64-bit versions.

Comment: Important to note that Windows XP Professional x64 Edition does *not* install in Bootcamp. Also, this list isn't correct for Lion.

Comment: I stand corrected then.